# How to use one shared config file in C++ Boost with a sink per application

Tags: c++, boost-log

I can easily create a config file to send messages to console, to logfile, to DebugView and to Eventlog but I didn't found out how to configure it that - as shared config file - Application "A" has 4 different sink sections than Application "B".

1. Is that possible?
2. How to implement that? (any links?)

My basic setup in the main function is following:

```
std::ifstream logConfiguration(getCwd() + "\\test-logging.ini");
try {
    boost::log::init_from_stream(logConfiguration);
    boost::log::add_common_attributes();
    boost::log::core::get()->add_global_attribute("Scope", boost::log::attributes::named_scope());
}
catch (std::exception e) {
    MYTRACE(error) << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Kind Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is that possible?

Yes, though not supported by Boost.Log out of the box.

> 2. How to implement that? (any links?)

You can implement reading the config file yourself or reuse the config file parser in Boost.Log. For example:

```
std::ifstream logConfiguration(getCwd() + "\\test-logging.ini");
boost::log::settings unifiedConfig = boost::log::parse_settings(logConfiguration);
```

Here, `settings` is a container with all the settings parsed from the file (see [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/basic_settings.html) and [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/basic_settings_section.html) for the documentation).

After parsing the file, you will have to construct a filtered settings container that corresponds to each particular application. How you do this depends on the unified settings file format. For example, if each of your application settings is stored in a separate subsection of the unified config, it could be as simple as this:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree const& unifiedPtree = unifiedConfig.property_tree();
boost::optional<boost::property_tree::ptree const&> ptreeA =
    unifiedPtree.get_child_optional("A");
if (ptreeA) {
    // We have some settings for application A
    boost::log::settings configA(*ptreeA);

    // ...
}
```

If you have a more involved format of the unified config, you may need to iterate over the `ptree` nodes to filter out the settings that pertain to different applications. See Boost.PropertyTree [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) for more details.

Lastly, when you have constructed the application-specific settings container, you can call [`init_from_settings`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html#log.detailed.utilities.setup.settings) in Boost.Log:

```
boost::log::init_from_settings(configA);
```